# How to use python-mock library

Tags: python, mocking

I have problems with understanding mock library in python.
Here is example: 
A have two files test.py and another.py

**test.py**

```
#!
from mock import patch
from another import C


class A(object):
    def method(self):
        return 2


@patch('another.C')
@patch('test.A')
class TestB(object):

    def test1(self, mA, mC):
        print mA, A
        print mC, C
```

**another.py**

```
class C(object):

    def a(self):
        return 3
```

So, question is "Why A have in output:

```
<MagicMock name='A' id='13985040'> <MagicMock name='A' id='13985040'>
<MagicMock name='C' id='13993936'> <class 'another.C'>
```

Why class from another.py can't be patched? 
In my case I have heavy function to test, and it imports classes from other files. 
So I cant understand how to them right.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With the Python mock library you always patch (mock) the function or class in the location that you are actually using it.

Since you are importing 'C' into 'test' and using it there you would patch it like this:

```
@patch('test.C')
@patch('test.A')
class TestB(object):

    def test1(self, mA, mC):
        print mA, A
        print mC, C
```

Which will give you output like this:

```
<MagicMock name='A' id='3070076204'> <MagicMock name='A' id='3070076204'>
<MagicMock name='C' id='3070084940'> <MagicMock name='C' id='3070084940'>
```

You can mock any class, method, or function that you want. But You need to mock the object in the location that it is actually being used.